# Java запуск каждую нечетную минуту

Tags: java

Можно ли сделать так, если можно то как, что бы при нажатии Jbutton, выполнялся определенный метод каждую нечетную минуту пока программа не будет закрыта?

Comment: Да, так сделать можно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, ходят слухи, что иногда нельзя.

Comment: Если используется `TimerService`, то запуск каждую нечётную минуту задается простой установкой расписания `minute="*/2"`. Правда TimerService - это функция серверов приложений JavaEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int currentMinute = LocalTime.now().getMinutes();
if(currentMinute % 2 != 0){
   // вызвать метод
}
```

Comment: Во второй строке одна левая скобка и две правых.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, гы-гыыыыы